# how to count new lines in a very big string?

Tags: php, string, count

The problem reduces to counting `\n` characters, so is there a function that can do it on a huge strings, since explode() wastes too much memory.

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->normalizeLineEndings()->count("\n")`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/ea3e40132e9d4ce27da337dae6286f2478b15f56/src/Str.php#L669) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str). This does two things: First, it normalizes all kinds of newlines (LF, CR, CRLF and Unicode newlines) to LF. Then it counts the LFs in a multibyte-safe way.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

[substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) should do the trick:

```
substr_count( $your_string, "\n" );
```

Comment: Thoughts about using PHP_EOL? I've been using the constant, and was curious about if I can just use \n, as you've outlined, instead. Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: @BobGregor This question asked specifically for a way to find "\n" but there is certainly nothing wrong with using PHP_EOL if you are looking for a way to find the end-of-line string in a cross-platform manner.

Comment: Note that double quotes `"` around `\n` are required: `substr_count( $your_string, "\n" );` works while `substr_count( $your_string, '\n' );` doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

i Think substr_count( $your_string, "\n" ); should be:

```
$numLine = substr_count( $your_string, "\n" ) +1;
```

But I use this:

```
$numLine = count(explode("\n",$your_string));
```

it always return correct result

Answer (score 7):

You can use PHP's `substr_count()` function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

`substr_count($myString, "\n");`

It will give you an integer with the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

```
$count=preg_match_all ('/\n/',$str);
```